# Getting system time in iPhone

Tags: iphone, date, time

I know that there is a method [NSDate date] which returns current date and time from iPhone clock. But if this clock time was changed manually it would rune my code.
Is there any opportunity to get world time, not current time from iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have correct current time by using ntp/sntp.

Following uris might help you to write your own implementation:

Simple NTP client for iOS : http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/

NSDate from time server: http://pathoneycutt.com/2010/12/nsdate-from-time-server/

Comment: +1 for the links. There might be some issues with getting an iOS app approved by apple if it launches external tasks as the second link suggests. Anybody knows if this will be accepted by Apple?