# How to get universal Time on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting system time in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055884/getting-system-time-in-iphone)

I have an app with a non.-renewable license, I need to obtain the current date-time that must be independent from the current device time. 
This value will be used to test if the license is expired.
I cant' use NSDate since the user can easly change the date-time setting of his device and hack this expiring check.

Is there a way to do that without using internet web service?

Comment: Obviously you can't do this unless you can get a connection to an NTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You can save (you can use a [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) a spent time after using your app.

1) App is foregrounded - start time

2) App is entered to background - stop time and save a spent time

3) In foreground check spent time and use him for check with license time